# Java interface "Alias"

Tags: java, interface, types

Consider the following two Java files that contain a simplified version of my issue

```
#a.java
package a;
public interface I {
 //...
}

#b.java
package b;
public interface I {
 //... (different stuff from a.I)
}
```

You'll notice within my project there are two interfaces named "I". This cannot be changed.
I am in a situation where I need to use both types inside a single class. Now of course, I could just reference each of their types as a.I and b.I, but I'm trying to avoid it for nothing other than maintaining readability.

I want to do something like this

```
interface B extends b.I {

}
```

This could let me use the interface of I by using B and, and a.I as just I by importing. The problem is that this doesn't work, let's take this concrete example using

```
interface MyList extends List<String> {
}

MyList l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This yields a type error. Why doesn't Java "know" that MyList extends List?

Also, I've tried casting in the above example, but it generates a ClassCastException

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is valid:

```
List<String> list = new MyList();
```

This is not:

```
MyList l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

`ArrayList` is not a `MyList`. They just have a common superinterface. That's why it doesn't work. Java "knows" `MyList` is a `List` but that doesn't mean you can assign a `List` to it.

Consider:

```
public interface MyList extends List<String> {
  void foo();
}

MyList l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.foo();
```

Obviously `ArrayList` does not have the `foo()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Java does know that `MyList` extends `List<String>`, but it also knows perfectly well that `ArrayList<String>` does NOT implement `MyList`.  I would strongly recommend removing ambiguities in the simplest, clearest, cleanest, most readable way: use `a.I` and `b.I`!

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast an `ArrayList<String>` into a `MyList` because `MyList` is not a super-class or super-interface of `ArrayList<String>`. Pretend you actually added a method to `MyList`, say `MyList.swizzle()`. What would happen if Java allowed the cast and then you called `l.swizzle()`?

I don't think you're going to find a satisfactory solution to this since Java does not have an `import as` type renaming statement. But implementing an interface to add its members to your class's namespace is contraindicated in Java 1.5: if you're going to go down that route, give  [`static import`](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) a try instead. It is the preferred idiom nowadays for doing what you're trying to do.